# Specman: Get number of assertion errors in test

Tags: specman

Is it possible to retrieve the number of verilog assertions failures in test from specman code? Is it possible to change the printing at the end of the test to include this data as well? For example:

```
    Checking is complete - 0 DUT errors, 0 DUT warnings, 1 Assertion failures.
```

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Doesn't the run anyway stop on the first `assert (...)` that fails?

Comment: No, it depends on how yo decide to handle assertion failures. It can b e convenient to see at the end of test also the total number of assertion failures.

Comment: Are we talking about Specman `assert <bool-exp>` command? I also think that the first encountered fail stops the run. `set_check` does not affect this.

Comment: Sorry, you were talking about _Verilog_ assertions. AFAIK Specman does not have direct access to the Verilog assertion report.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can get the verilog assertion count using external C-DPI via UCIS into the Specman world.  In practice it is easy to merge the simulation log file into the Specman log file and post-process it.